# Arbitrary amount of fields in Modelform

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

At first let me excuse for my English, it's not my native language.

I need to construct a table of, say, 1000 rows and 5 cells in each row, so i've decided to have Cell and Row models.

**models.py**

```
class Cell(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    row = models.ForeignKey('Row')

class Row(models.Model):
    pass
```

The contents of the table cells is unimportant (at the current stage i'm filling it with random data).

What i need is to be able to add a new rows. The form should have an input field (it's nature is absolutely inconsiderable) in each cell. I prefer to use a Modelform:

**forms.py**

```
class RowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Row
        fields = ??? <- problem here.
```

How can i get a Modelform that supplies input fields for each cell (keeping in mind that the amount of the cells may change in future)? I hope i've expressed my needs quite clearly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The purpose of ModelForm is to create forms based on your model. But your Row model doesn't know anything about your cells, or the number of cells you should have in a row. Couldn't your cells be fields of the row? If not, you will have to create your own form.

Comment: Ok, let it be my own form. Is it possible to make it agnostic of amount of cells?

Comment: You can have a look at the Django doc there https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/ for inspiration!

Comment: Thanks Thierry, i'll surely look!

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking this. In database speak, a cell is the place where a column and a row intersect. You needn't in fact you shouldn't create a model called cell. All you need is

```
class Row(models.Model)
    col1 = models.SomeField()
    col2 = models.SomeField()
    col3 = models.SomeField()
    col4 = models.SomeField()
```

Answer (score 0):

I got what i needed by following code:

**forms.py**

```
class RowForm(forms.Form):
    cell = forms.CharField(label='Ячейка', max_length=100)


class RowFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    min_num = 5
    max_num = 5
    absolute_max = 5
    extra = 0
    form = RowForm
    can_order = False
    can_delete = False
    validate_max = False
    validate_min = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RowFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for i in range(0, NUMBER_OF_CELLS):
            self[i].fields['cell'].label += " %d" % (i + 1)
```